# ipywidgets dynamic creation of checkboxes and selection of data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I want to create a list of checkboxes so users can select from a list of data. I've created checkboxes for each piece of data and I'd now like the ticking of these checkboxes to add data to a list.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

data = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]

selected_data = []

checkboxes = [widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description=label) for label in data]

widgets.VBox(children=checkboxes)
```

I'd like to do something along the lines of

```py
def add_to_selected(d):
    selected_data.append(d)

checkboxes[0].observe(add_to_selected)
```

Where this would add a value to the `selected_data` list. I don't know how to get the checkboxes in the VBox to behave like this.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and describe exactly how it's failing or not meeting your expectations.

Comment: @glibdud I've added a minimal working example and what I've tried but unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution that works but I feel is quite hacky. I'd appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions on a way to simplify it.

This solutions allows the creation of a checkbox for each key in the `data` dictionary. On clicking the checkbox the selected key is added to the `selected_data` list.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

data = {"label_1":"data_1", "label_2":"data_2", "label_3":"data_3"}

names = []
checkbox_objects = []
for key in data:
    checkbox_objects.append(widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description=key))
    names.append(key)

arg_dict = {names[i]: checkbox for i, checkbox in enumerate(checkbox_objects)}

ui = widgets.VBox(children=checkbox_objects)

selected_data = []
def select_data(**kwargs):
    selected_data.clear()

    for key in kwargs:
        if kwargs[key] is True:
            selected_data.append(key)

    print(selected_data)

out = widgets.interactive_output(select_data, arg_dict)
display(ui, out)
```

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm quite late here but this may help someone else in the future.

In Jupyter, this is your first block:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
data = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]
checkboxes = [widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description=label) for label in data]
output = widgets.VBox(children=checkboxes)
display(output)
```

The above will output a VBox with the four choices in the list variable 'data'. Then to get the list of selected values, you can do:

```
selected_data = []
for i in range(0, len(checkboxes)):
    if checkboxes[i].value == True:
        selected_data = selected_data + [checkboxes[i].description]
print(selected_data)
```

Note that I moved the selected_data list from before the selection to after. The reason for this is so that the self replacing selected_data portion of the for loop doesn't continuously add on the previously chosen selections if you were to run multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the data in the checkbox and get a list of values.

widget

```
data = {
    "key1":"value1"
    , "key2":"value2"
    , "key3":"value3"
}

checkboxes = [widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description=label) for label in data]
output = widgets.VBox(children=checkboxes)
display(output)
```

get value list

```
selected_data = []
for i in range(0, len(checkboxes)):
    if checkboxes[i].value == True:
        selected_data.append(data[str([checkboxes[i].description][0])])
print(selected_data)
```