# multiselect dropdown using ipywidgets?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I wanted to create a multiselect dropdown with checkboxes using ipywidgets, but with dropdown it is possible to select only one option. Would there be any possible way to implement this? ipywidgets also has an html widget, can this be done with html? If it isnt possible to achieve this, then what would be the best alternative approach?

Comment: I am pretty sure this feature is not available currently with ipywidgets. SelectMultiple is the only widget that achieves this. However, you could create multiple dropdown lists?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), describe your problem and share code snippets and/or sources of what you have attempted so far so others can better understand and assist you.

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved with the current ipywidgets. ipyvuetify might suit your needs. https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify

Comment: Perhaps a way towards the solution to your problem is there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57230942/8844500